# Is there an open source or shareware program like Quickjump? allowing jumping to a folder with a few keystrokes?

Tags: user-interface

QuickJump
see http://www.techhit.com/QuickJump/open_navigate_windows_folders.html

Answer (score 0):

[Launchy](http://www.launchy.net/) is the only alternative I have found so far. It works if you tell it what folders to index, and remember checking off the "Include directories" for each of them. It's quick and works ok, but not excellent. For instance, it does not show the path to the directory, so if you have multiple hits you need to guess which one it is. But I can open my Downloads folder with Alt+Space and then writing "do".

It is open source and supports plugins, so extending it to show the path is possible.